# Recycleview item size not work in dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I made a `DialogFragment` which has a `ViewPager` in it, and the `ViewPager` contains `Fragments` that have `Recyclerview` in it. The problem I face is that there is only one item in `Recyclerview` and the item size in `Recyclerview` is incorrect.

This is My `DialogFragment`

```
class StickerSelectorPopup: DialogFragment(), StickerPickerAdapter.Listener {
private lateinit var mAdapter: FeedFragment.Adapter
private lateinit var mViewPager: ViewPager
private lateinit var mTabs: TabLayout
private var isFirstTime = true
private var mUserUid = ""

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view_sticker_tab, container, false)

    mViewPager = mView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
    mTabs = mView.findViewById(R.id.result_tabs)
    mAdapter = FeedFragment.Adapter(childFragmentManager)

    return mView
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            mAdapter.addFragment(StickerPickerFragment.newInstance(mutableListOf("chat.gif", "fhere.gif", "hai.gif", "sedih.gif"), 2, this@StickerSelectorPopup, "gabut_woman"), "Gabut Woman")
    mAdapter.addFragment(StickerPickerFragment.newInstance(mutableListOf("8.gif"), 2, this@StickerSelectorPopup, "gabut_man"), "Gabut Man")

    mViewPager.adapter = mAdapter

    mTabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager)
}
}
```

This is The `Fragment` load by `ViewPager`

```
class StickerPickerFragment : Fragment() {
private var mListSticker = mutableListOf<String>()
private var mStickerUid = 0
private var mFolder = ""
private lateinit var mListener: StickerPickerAdapter.Listener
private lateinit var mRecycleView: RecyclerView

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sticker_picker, container, false)
    mRecycleView = v.findViewById(R.id.adStickerPickerRvMain)
    mRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    mRecycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context!!)
    mRecycleView.adapter = StickerPickerAdapter(mFolder, mStickerUid, mListener)

    (mRecycleView.adapter as StickerPickerAdapter).addAll(mListSticker)

    return  v
}
}
```

This is `DialogFragment` xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/gray_btn_bg_pressed_color"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This Fragment load by ViewPager XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.stickerpicker.StickerPickerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/adStickerPickerRvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/amber_100"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This item `RecyclerviewAdapter` xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@color/blue_100">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/adStickerItemImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:contentDescription="Sticker"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It works only with 1 item. If there is more than 1 item, then it only shows the first item and the item view size is not right.

[1 item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u4rI.png)
[more than 1 item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RThkq.png)

blue is the background of item adapter
and the yellow is the background of Recyclerview in Fragment

Comment: Welcome to so. You can try `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the sticker ImageView. If that doesnt help I have some questions to narrow down the problem: Can you please include the `StickerPickerAdapter`? Do the views behave as expected, when they are not in a `DialogFragment`?

Comment: Thank You. silly of me. this has been solved. because ip of localhost changed and the image not load, the one image is from temp folder of Glide so its still loaded without internet.